# AWS - How can I setup RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, putty, amazon-rds

I am trying to setup RDS on my AWS account. I created the RDS instance, But I am not able to access the database interface. I am trying to access it using putty, But it is saying - "Command not found".

Please clarify whether I am missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention the RDS Database engine you are using, but here are some general tips.

1. Use a local database client (such as [mysql workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) for mysql)
2. Make sure your RDS security group allows your local ip address to access the RDS instance on the correct port.

If you give more information about your setup we'll be able to help you more.

Comment: The steps I followed are 
1. Created EC2 instance.
2. Created RDS Database instance.

I am able to login in putty, trying to execute mysql command - Its giving me command not found.

I want to access the created database...How should I do that?

How should I link EC2 and RDS - Using security groups?

Please clarify

Thanks,
Bhairav

Comment: @BhairavPati, l think this will help you: [RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html), [Security Groups](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html). On your EC2, make sure you have a mysql client installed.